# Is using a "Makefile.defs" file a good practice?

Tags: c++, c, makefile

I'm newish to C++ and GNU make, and I'm writing a C++ library. In the main directory I have is a Makefile that compiles the library into a shared object (.so). Then I have a subdirectory where I have some example programs using that library. These programs have separate Makefiles that first build the .so using the Makefile in the main directory, link the .so, and then compile the program.

The problem is there are variables in the main Makefile (`$(CPP)`, `$(FLAGS)`, `$(CPPFLAGS)`, etc.) that are needed in the example Makefiles to compile the example programs. I could copy and paste the variables into each example Makefile, but this seems exhaustive and hard to track. One solution I've seen is to have a Makefile.defs file that defines all the relevant compilation variables which is then included by both the main Makefile and the example program Makefiles. Is this a good solution? Is there any problems with this? Are there any other solutions?

Comment: In my experience, good practice these days is to transition from building directly with hand-crafted Makefiles to cmake (and writing a CMakeLists.txt file instead).  (Cmake's syntax is every bit as annoying and obscure as gmake's, but it pays for itself the first time you need to compile under Windows and don't have to write an entire separate build system to do it, plus it allows other projects that use cmake -- which is many of them these days -- to include your library as a dependency with a minimum of hassle)

Comment: Using an include file is fine.  There are no problems with it.  Another option is to pass all the variables on the command line for the sub-makes, but this requires you to list them and it can sometimes (depending on the options) run into shell quoting issues.

Comment: If your top Makefile does not depend of from where make is invoked you could also try to include it in your local Makefiles. This would naturally import the variable definitions (and also maybe the specification of the flow to build the library, which could save a sub-make). To obtain this independence adding `topdir := $(dir $(lastword $(MAKEFILE_LIST)))` at the beginning of your top Makefile is a starting point.

Comment: Have a look at https://github.com/cppfw/prorab It might be very useful in your case, when you have a lib and separate test/example programs with independent makefiles. It allows defining build configurations (see `prorab-config` in reference) which is shared between your lib and apps, and there you can define common compilation/linking flags etc.